# Dafny - Convert a natural number into a sequence of digits

Tags: sequence, dafny

Following up on a previous question I had, I am trying to write a code that turns a nat n into a sequence s, for example: n=123 will turn into s=<1,2,3>

the code has some predicates I added which should help with the proof, but no matter what I write, danfy isn't satisfied...

I've been looking for similar questions and reading examples of dafny but without success

```
// returns true if n is of length |length| (for example: true for 1223 4 , false for 1223 2)
predicate NumberOfDecimalDigits(n: nat, length: nat) 
    decreases length
{
    (length == 1 && IsSingleDecimalDigit(n)) ||
    (length > 1 && !IsSingleDecimalDigit(n) && NumberOfDecimalDigits(n/10, length-1)) 
}

// gets a sequnce & a number and returns true if they are the same
predicate DecimalDigits(q: seq<nat>, n: nat) 
{
    IsDecimal(q) && SeqToNat(q) == n
} 
// returns true if it's a signle-digit number
predicate IsSingleDecimalDigit(d: nat) { 0 <= d && d <= 9 } 

// returns true if the number is zero or has no leading zeros
predicate NoLeadingZeros(q: seq<nat>) 
    requires |q| != 0
{
    q[0] == 0 ==> |q| == 1
}

// returns true if it's a sequence of digits (which creates a decimal number)
predicate IsDecimal(q: seq<nat>) 
{
    |q| != 0 && (forall d :: d in q  ==> IsSingleDecimalDigit(d)) && NoLeadingZeros(q)
}

// requires q is decimal - returns natural number out of a sequnce 
// recursive function
function SeqToNat(q: seq<nat>): nat 
    requires IsDecimal(q)
{
    if |q| == 1 then q[0] else SeqToNat(q[..|q|-1])*10+q[|q|-1]
}

method {:verify false} buildSeqFromNat (n: nat, length: nat) returns (s: seq<nat>)
    requires NumberOfDecimalDigits(n, length) == true;
    ensures DecimalDigits(s, n) == true
    ensures length == |s|
{

}
```

Adding context as per request:

```
// n=123 , length = 3 , s = <1,2,3>
method {:verify true} buildSeqFromNat (n: nat, length: nat) returns (s: seq<nat>)
    requires NumberOfDecimalDigits(n, length) == true;
    ensures DecimalDigits(s, n) == true
    ensures IsDecimal(s)
    ensures length == |s|
{
    var a := new nat[length];
    recursiveFunc(n, length, a);
    assert DecimalDigits(a[..], n);
    s := a[..];
} 

method {:verify true} recursiveFunc (n: nat, last: nat, a: array<nat>)
    requires 0 < last <= a.Length
    requires NumberOfDecimalDigits(n,last)
    ensures a[..last] == Rec(n)
    ensures IsDecimal(a[..last])
    ensures SeqToNat(a[..last]) == n
    ensures DecimalDigits(a[..last], n)
    modifies a
    decreases n
{
    if (n < 10){
        a[last-1] := n;
    } else{
        var tmp := n%10;
        assert IsSingleDecimalDigit(tmp);
        a[last-1] := tmp;
        recursiveFunc(n/10, last-1, a);
    }
}

function Rec (n: nat) : seq<nat>
    decreases n
{
    if n < 10 then [n] else Rec(n/10)+[n%10]
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, Could you please at least post your initial skeletton of the method buildSeqFromNat? Like, how would you build `s` ?

Comment: @MikaëlMayer I've added this part to the original post. thank you!